# ecb installation error on windows version emacs 24.3

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I have emacs 24.3 installed on windows, and tried to install ecb version 20130406.1406 through the package manager, however, during the compiling process, i had the following error message:

> jn-file-tree.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-node
>
> Compiling file c:/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-tree-node.el at Fri Apr 12 19:03:13 2013
>   jn-tree-node.el:32:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-utils
>
> Compiling file c:/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-tree-view.el at Fri Apr 12 19:03:13 2013
>   jn-tree-view.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-window
>
> Compiling file c:/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-utils.el at Fri Apr 12 19:03:13 2013
>
> Compiling file c:/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-window.el at Fri Apr 12 19:03:13 2013
>   jn-window.el:44:25:Error: Invalid lambda variable (parent jn-window-container)
>
> Compiling file c:/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/test.el at Fri Apr 12 19:03:13 2013
>   test.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-view
>   ...

did any one encounter this before?

anyway, despite the above errors, it was installed, and i was able to activate ecb by run M-x ecb-activate, however i got an error message as follow:

> The ECB is now deactivated.
>   ecb-clean-up-after-activation-failure: ECB 2.40: Errors during the layout setup of ECB. (error-type: void-variable, error-data: (ecb-examples-bufferinfo-buffer-name))

thanks alot!

Comment: I am getting a similar error with a later version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129637/emacs-24-3-1-cedet-2-0-built-in-and-ecb-20131116-1319-errors-during-the-layou?noredirect=1#comment30001079_20129637

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue, use this to fix the activate failure:

```
(setq ecb-examples-bufferinfo-buffer-name nil)
```

According to:
[Emacs 24.3.1 CEDET 2.0 (built in) and ECB 20131116.1319: Errors during the layout setup of ECB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129637/emacs-24-3-1-cedet-2-0-built-in-and-ecb-20131116-1319-errors-during-the-layou)