# Emacs 24.3.1 CEDET 2.0 (built in) and ECB 20131116.1319: Errors during the layout setup of ECB

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

Using the CEDET that comes with Emacs 24.3.1 and the ECB that is in Melpa, I get the following trying `ecb-activate`:

```
All requirements for ECB 2.40 fulfilled - Enjoy it! [2 times]
The ECB is now deactivated.
ecb-clean-up-after-activation-failure: ECB 2.40: Errors during the layout setup of ECB.  
    (error-type: void-variable, error-data: (ecb-examples-bufferinfo-buffer-name))
```

Here is the info from the emacs pacakage manager:

```
ecb is an installed package.

     Status: Installed in `/home/Smith/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/'.
     Version: 20131116.1319
     Summary: a code browser for Emacs

cedet is a built-in package.

    Status: Built-in.
    Version: 2.0
    Summary: Setup CEDET environment
```

My question, how to get this to work. Alex Ott's [fork of ECB](https://github.com/alexott/ecb) seems to indicate it should.

Comment: hmmm, that's very strange - ecb-examples isn't referred anywhere in the ECB itself... Feel free to file an issue on github...

Comment: I just downloaded the ECB package from MELPA, and run Emacs without any config, loaded the ECB into it, and everything works fine. Can you enable `toggle-debug-on-error`, run `ecb-activate` again, and post the stacktrace to alexott at gmail

Comment: I tried starting EMACS with just ecb and got a similar error: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "ECB 2.40: Errors during the layout setup of ECB. (error-type: error, error-data: (\"Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size\"))")

Comment: Having the same error here... There is no ecb-examples in the ECB, but it is  somehow being added to ecb-autocontrol/sync-fcn-register . I'll try to go further on this later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to get past this error after executing this command in the `*scratch*`

> (setq ecb-examples-bufferinfo-buffer-name nil)

YMMV.